# How to debug Ubuntu startup process

Tags: ubuntu, login, startup, debugging, unity

./Hello!

My Ubuntu `16.04 LTS` installation, probably after installing updates, now unable to start Unity after user login. It just freezes! 
 Google'ing won't help this time :/ 
I.e. OS boots, show login screen, but Unity hangs during startup and never finished it. I'm even unable to switch to the another console, system does not respond.

How to debug such kind of problems? What can i do to repair system? 
I don't want to reinstall it - so Windows way it is :(

Comment: reboot and use `journalctl -ex`, then search for you process and figure out what is happening

Comment: if you have closed drivers for graphics adapter `dkms status`. Sometimes dkms donot built the driver to  a new kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not login graphically, but you can still login in text mode. Switch to the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd>) and log in. Then you can look at the logs.

First, begin with the `~/.xsession-errors` file in your home directory. You can also execute `ls -ltra ~ | tail` to see the last changes in your home. Maybe there are other log files to read? As a last resort `find ~ -mmin -15 -type f` will give you all the files in your home that have changed in the last 15 minutes, that may be interesting (is there a [core file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump)? a crash report? etc.)

If you don't find anything in your home directory, you can look at the system-wide log files in `/var/log`. Begin with `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. If you find nothing, you can execute `ls -ltr /var/log | tail` to have a list of the log files that have changed lately. Read the one that have changed at the time you logged in (or since). You may have to `sudo -s` in order to look into some of these files.

Comment: The problem was in `nouveau` driver - after installation of proprietary NVidia drivers the problem disappears.

Comment: What is Fn please? I don't have this key on my keyboard

Comment: @Richard some key like F1-F11

Comment: @jarno. Thanks. I eventually found you have to push shift and escape to start the boot menu